# Which was this comic where Spider-Man brought cookies for the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man

[image: Which comic book is this panel from ?]

This looks really fun to read. I want to know what happened here, which comic issue is this from ?

Comment: Now right-click on it and click "[search Google for image](https://tinyurl.com/mqyhutz)" and the first 50 results are your answer

Comment: @Valorum I just did, and most of those don't have the issue number. I had to go to _page 2_ of the Google search to find it, so this is _not trivial at all_.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - The very first 'real' result has the issue number in the title as have the next seven links under it

Comment: @Valorum You know Google results are personalized, right?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - I've just tried it on google.com and google.fr with an anonymous browser window. The result was top ten on all attempts.

Answer (score 3):

### Amazing Spider-Man (Vol. 3) #2

[image]

Preview:

- [Newsarama](http://www.newsarama.com/21129-is-that-silk-studying-spidey-in-amazing-spider-man-2-preview.html)

Sources and synopses:

- [Spiderfan.org](http://www.spiderfan.org/comics/reviews/spiderman_amazing_v3/002.html)
- [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_3_2)

Comment: Ahem; https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjK4ND5o-zSAhXmDcAKHdMGDnMQFghUMBM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fviewcomic.com%2Famazing-spider-man-002-2014%2F&usg=AFQjCNG26k_nND7snnERHWPftkGcI11U3Q&sig2=dpKECrW60A8Kny7d0x9sJQ

Comment: @Valorum Oh, very nice. Is it legal?

Comment: Friggin' ninja :D [Here's a preview](http://www.newsarama.com/21129-is-that-silk-studying-spidey-in-amazing-spider-man-2-preview.html) of this issue, that panel uncluded

Comment: Possibly legal. I didn't look too hard.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the link to preview to your answer.